# OSGi bundle fails to resolve intermittently

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I have written an OSGi bundle which has dependency on following spring framework bundle and some other similar JARs.

```
org.springframework.core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Most of the times, the spring framework core bundle starts without any problem. But at times, the bundle fails to resolve dependency. Following error is thrown on click of start button in felix console:

```
*ERROR* [FelixDispatchQueue] org.springframework.core FrameworkEvent ERROR (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.core [494]: Unable to resolve 494.0: missing requirement [494.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream.events)(version>=0.0.0)))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.core [494]: Unable to resolve 494.0: missing requirement [494.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.stream.events)(version>=0.0.0))
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4095)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2114)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1368)
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also, some other spring framework JAR's too throw the same error and fail to resolve/start.

```
*ERROR* [FelixDispatchQueue] org.springframework.beans FrameworkEvent ERROR (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.beans [495]: Unable to resolve 495.0: missing requirement [495.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.logging)(version>=1.1.1)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.beans [495]: Unable to resolve 495.0: missing requirement [495.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.logging)(version>=1.1.1)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4095)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2114)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1368)
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As per my understanding, javax.* packages are provided by system bundle. Can anyone please help me in solving this ?

**EDIT:**

This is happening when I kill the java process. Also this is happening for all bundles which have following imports :

```
javax.jcr
javax.swing
javax.xml.stream.events
org.apache.commons.logging
javax.servlet
javax.sql
javax.script
javax.net
```

When I kill the java process and I restart my AEM, I am facing this issue. When I uninstall the bundle and restart my AEM and reinstall the bundle, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Only the `java.*` packages are provided by the system bundle by default. All other packages have to be defined using the framework property  `org.osgi.framework.system.packages`. Each OSGi framework has a default config for this property that is also often dependent on the Java Runtime Version used.

If a javax package is not exported by the system bundle but you know it is available in your jra then you can use the framework property `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra` . It allows to define packages that are to be exported in addition to the default ones.

One thing that is strange is that you write that you only sometimes have the error. I would expect it to either work all the time or fail all the time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the javax.* packages are exported from my system bundle. I double checked that. And also the issue is intermittent. And I am, at this point unable to pin point the cause which leads to this error.

Comment: I am also facing the same. It occurs rarely. But when it occurs I have to uninstall all spring bundles restart the bundle. Then when I install the same bundles, it starts working.

Comment: Do you use Require-Bundle anywhere?

Comment: No. I am not using Require Bundle any where. This is happening if i kill the java process. I have added this as an edit to my question.

Comment: I think it is an AEM problem then. If it only happens when you kill the process then it is not really generally OSGi related.